# weekly sales report summary mysql php

Tags: php, mysql

I have a table and I want to retrieve info from table as weekly, means how many booth booked in a week

```
SELECT  `sold_by` , COUNT(`booth_number` ) ,  `Date`  FROM  `registration`  
 WHERE `Date` BETWEEN DATE_SUB(CURDATE(), INTERVAL 7 DAY) AND CURDATE() 
GROUP BY `sold_by` ";

//$result="SELECT count(`booth_number`),`sold_by`  
       FROM `registration` GROUP BY `sold_by`  ";
```

Comment: -2
down vote
favorite
i have a table and i want to retrive info from table as weekly, means how many booth booked in a week

Comment: I understood your question and added an answer :-)

Answer (score 0):

Is this what you are looking for?

```
SELECT sold_by, YEARWEEK(Date), COUNT(booth_number) FROM registration GROUP BY sold_by, YEARWEEK(Date)
```

**Test it out here**: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/ae782/1

Comment: i want the summary of the sales in week by the sales persons

Comment: i want weekly sales report by the sales person